# PowerShell map persistent sharepoint path

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, mapping

I'm trying to map the path to a SharePoint document library in a persistent way. It's strange that this works fine:

```
$Sharepoint = '\\domain.net\stuff\Documents\Folders - Permission matrix'
New-PSDrive -Name P -Root $Sharepoint -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $Credentials
```

But this doesn't work:

```
New-PSDrive -Persist -Name P -Root $Sharepoint -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $Credentials
New-PSDrive : The network resource type is not correct
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSDrive -Persist -Name P -Root $Sharepoint -PSProvider FileSystem -Credentia ...
```

The commands are both using the same `PSProvider` but one is persistent and the other one not. How can I have this persistent without reverting to `net use`?

Comment: Interesting, I'm able to reproduce and must second that this makes no sense

Comment: Not able to reproduce in my case (Windows 7, PowerShell 4.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem a few weeks back in a script which mysteriously stopped worked whilst I was developing it, seems to be a Windows error 66 rather than Powershell [as explained here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978764.aspx)

Here is an alternative to net use which uses credentials

```
# map drive using credentials
(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("$LocalDrive","\\$computer\$drive",$false,$($credentials.username),$($credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password))
```

I tend to use PSDrive like this

```
    # discover and delete
    if (Get-PSDrive -Name Results -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { Remove-PSDrive -Name Results -Scope Global | Out-Null }

    # create using credentials
    if ((New-PSDrive -Name Results -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\server\share" -Credential $Credentials -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)  { $WSHShell.popup(“You do not have access to the results repository“,0,””,0) | Out-Null }

    # call from a separate function
    (Get-PSDrive -Name Results).root
```

It might just be that a reboot will solve the problem because I cannot recreate the issue today.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, turns out Windows 2016 and 2019 needs WEBDav Redirection installed.

I was getting error 53, when trying to map a SharePoint library.